# Working in a non IT firm as a developer

Tags: career-development

I started working at a place just a couple of days ago, I was working as a freelance web developer but applied and got selected for the job. The firm is not an IT /development firm but required developers for their website. The website is core to the working of the firm as it generates business leads.

Now the problem is as this not a pure IT firm they don't have a team of programmers or IT  professionals whatsoever. So I have to start right from installing all the necessary software and tools to revamping their websites. That would not have been such a huge deal but none of their project files open without causing trouble, if I am able to open them they won't run or compile in the first place (These are all. NET based websites). Starting from scratch doesn't seem like a good idea because there's a lot back end that I alone would have to re do. I have spent the last 4 days trying to make the project run but every time a new problem arises.

My question is it worth my time to work hard in this organization, to get the results they want. Would it add enough value to my resume at the end of the day?

Comment: you're only interested in how it looks on your resume?

Comment: Didn't the previous developer(s) of the website leave any documentation behind about how to set-up everything?

Comment: Is there no possibility to contact the previous developers?

Comment: Good for you for watching out for yourself first. Last thing you would want is spending three years here with no exit strategy.

Comment: A couple of days is a very short time. In scenarios where you inherit a poor legacy codebase with no help, you'll need to give yourself *at least* a 2-3 weeks to even get started. That said, the challenge is not primarily a technical one,  the challenge you *will* have is managing the expectations of the people you are working for and getting cooperation from them-- that could easily be insurmountable for an individual. That's why companies often hire consulting firms to do this kind of work.

Answer (score 10):

So, you need to make a decision here.

Are you looking at this job as a job, or are you looking at it as a resume filler?

If this isn't the work that you see yourself doing for more than a year, do yourself and your employer a favour and leave.

If this is a job that you want to develop and make a real contribution to this company, then forget your resume filling criteria and concentrate on your job (doing this will reflect positively on your resume anyway).

The fact that you've been employed (as opposed to being taken on as a contractor/freelancer) means that the company is investing in your future and hoping that you can contribute to their web presence.

Spending a week trying to get someone else's code/project working isn't an unknown thing.  It can take a long time to pick up the reigns and make something work.  This is not a brick wall.

Decide in your head whether you want to stay or not.  If you want to stay, make a plan of work - sort out what you need to achieve and what time/tools you need to get to where you want to be.

If you decide to leave, then be aware of how this reflects in your resume.  It's rare that you drop into a job that's smooth running from day one.

The more work you put into making a situation work, the better it reflects in your resume (up until the point where you're beating a dead horse, when it surely is time to move on).

Comment: You could even end up building a team, becoming a senior or lead developer, and produce something not only valuable to your company, but marketable to others. How's that for a quality resume?

Answer (score 4):

> My question is it worth my time to work hard in this organization, to get the results they want. Would it add enough value to my resume at the end of the day?

Yes, a resume with completed, successful projects on it looks a lot better than one without.

Comment: Leaving a job after a couple of days because it was "too much work", would certainly not win you any points with me if I were the one looking to hire you for your next job.

Comment: @mickeyf maybe, but who would list a job that they left after two days on their resume in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

The "value" of a position on your resume is hard to quantify as it's very subjective and while there will be large amounts of overlap you can't predict exactly what future hiring managers will be looking for. So my rule of thumb is to evaluate it as "what would *I* rather hire?"

So doing that, ask yourself whether you'd be more interested in hiring:

- Someone whose resume can describe how they built an in-house development department by themselves, from scratch.

or

- Someone who basically gave up after four days and coasted because it looked like they might actually have some work to do.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, it is worth it.** In fact, being one of the only developers in a company carries unique opportunities to show your initiative and capability.

Unfortunately, almost any developer job will require days or weeks of setup time before becoming productive. If you're willing to consider quitting just because you've spent four days setting up projects, then you may not have the necessary expectations or determination to excel in this role.

Answer (score 0):

If you like doing the type of tasks associated with the job, then keep doing it. Your resume can reflect everything you are doing. There is a vast ocean of companies that want your skills anyplace you want.

You will use all of your experience in the future (if you have a lot of years to work) If you become a supervisor over a diverse IT group down the road, you will know more of what you are talking about, depending on how much things change.

If you aspire to be a specialist only, or get away from working with non-IT people, then only the relevant part of your experience will help you in the future. If the developer side of your current experience is watered down you may fall behind in your goals.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is it worth my time to work hard in this organization, to
>   get the results they want.

If you value being paid, it's probably worth your time to work hard.

Alternatively, you can find a new job.